# Using an array in preg_replace to reduce codes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is it possible to use an array in preg_replace to reduce the codes needed? So, something like this:

```
$text = "1 2 3";
$array = array(1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three");

preg_replace($array, $text);

echo $text;
```

**Result:**

```
1 2 3
```

**Needed Result:**

```
one two three
```

Comment: `strtr($text, $array);`

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes! It works! What does strtr stand for? String something, right? What does tr stand for?

Comment: @Rizier123 hello :) Make that an answer !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php str=string, tr=translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mixed preg_replace ( **mixed** $pattern , **mixed** $replacement , mixed $subject,... <sup>[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)</sup>

```
$text = "1 2 3";

$array = array(
'/1/' => "one",
'/2/' => "two",
'/3/' => "three");

$text = preg_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $text);
```

[Demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/450145) (as mentioned in the comments, there is no need to use regex here)